# Cannot run exec() from apache centos

Tags: php, apache, centos

I am trying to run an executable in centos by calling it from php using the exec() command. The exe runs in the command line but when I call it through php and check from the browser it does not execute the exe. I have set the file permissions for the exe. Is there anything I need to change in the apache configuration file to enable to run an executable file?

Comment: Maybe exec() is disabled in php.ini under disabled_functions?

Answer (score 2):

check the `disabled_functions` string on your `php.ini` and remove the `exec` function if it's listed.

you can also enable-it by reseting your `disabled_function` in your `.htaccess` if you have one :

```
php_flag disable_function
```

edit : as @nrathaus said. if you cannot change the `php.ini` file or you cannot override the settings in the `.htaccess` (eg : if you have a simple website-hosting solution), you have to contact the admin of this server and ask him to enable the `exec` function.

Comment: You are assuming that he has the ability to override that `.htaccess`, it might be that he is running on a shared server, and it is disabled (globally)

Comment: @nrathaus : yes. then if it's the case, we can't help him more. he has to contact the admin of the server.

Comment: I agree, that is why I suggest you write that as well, that everything is nice as long as the server admin didn't disable it in the php.ini :}

Comment: There is no disbled functions in the pnp.ini its empty. And I tried exec('whoami') and it runs ok. But I am not able to run my exe. Is it because of the permission? Where should I put the exe?

Comment: hmm. did you write the full path to your executable ?
eg : `exec('C:\yourPath\hello.exe')`